# MATLAB: Sum Variable Number of Vectors

Tags: matlab, vector, sum

I have to sum multiple vectors, but their number varies.

I have:

```
g1 = [1 3 4 5 3 4 6 2 3 4 6 6]
g2 = ....  
.
.
.
gn = [3 4 5 6 4 5 6 2 4 7 8 9]
```

And I have to sum all of them:

```
G=sum(g1 to gn)
```

How do I do that?

Comment: It appears to me that you have a list of scalars (not vectors) and the obvious way would be, to use a vector instead: `g(1)=134534623466; g(2)=35645624564524572` etc.

Comment: Yes, that's my mistake of the representation. The 'g' are VECTORS, not scalars...

Comment: Are all of the vectors of the same size? Do you want to sum element-wise to obtain a _vector_, or to sum all elements of all vectors to obtain a _number_?

Comment: Yes, they are the same size, and I want to obtain a vector, not a number. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would me much easier if you stored all your vectors in a matrix `g`, one vector in each row. Then the desired result would be simply `sum(g)`.

If you really need to have each vector in a different variable, you can compute the sum with `eval` within a loop:

```
result = zeros(size(g1)); % initialize sum
for ii = 1:n
  eval(['result = result + g' num2str(ii) ';']) % add ii-th vector to the sum
end
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

> sum(arrayfun(@(i) eval(['g' num2str(i)]),1:n))

(sums all scalars with name pattern gX, where X=1...n)

Comment: I tried it like that:____________n=mes-1; % = 8____________            Gxx_avg = sum(arrayfun(@(i) eval(['Gxx' num2str(i)]),1:n))             

______________But it gives me:_____________________

??? Error using ==> eval
Undefined function or variable 'Gxx1'.

Comment: @Mercury Same error here. Your approach was very good, but apparently `eval` can't be used in an anonymous function