# MATLAB: SUM / Average of vectors

Tags: matlab, vector, sum, average

I have to calculate the average of "n" VECTORS like that:

```
Gxx_avg = (Gxx1+Gxx2+Gxx3+Gxx4+Gxx5+Gxx6+Gxx7+Gxx8)/8;
```

The problem is that each time their number is different => n =, 1,2,3,4,....n
In the end Gxx_avg must be a VECTOR as well.
Thanks!

Comment: This is eseentially the same as your previous question about sum of vectors! Just divide by `n`at the end http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618750/matlab-sum-variable-number-of-vectors/19620500

Comment: You're right Luis. I tried to use 2 different explanations as the first one seems to be not quite well structured.

Comment: Just got your answer on the previous page - THANKS!!!

Comment: You should seriously consider restructuring your code to make one single `Gxx` matrix instead of many vectors. If each vector has a different length then either pad with NaN or you a cell array. Then you can eliminate the need for `eval` and make your code easier to follow, debug and maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Gxx_avg = zeros(size(Gxx1));
for ii = 1:mes-1
  eval(['Gxx_avg = Gxx_avg + Gxx' num2str(ii) ';'])
end
```

Thanks to : **Luis Mendo**
[MATLAB: Sum Variable Number of Vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618750/matlab-sum-variable-number-of-vectors)

Answer (score 1):

You could make each vector the column of a single matrix and use the `mean` function.

Example:

```
G = [Gxx1 Gxx2 Gxx3];
Gavg = mean(G,2);
```

This will take the mean across dimension 2, which means each row will become the mean of all values in that row.

Comment: How can I use this, if I don't know the number of Gxx's ?

Comment: Do you have an example of how you are generating Gxx*?

Comment: Not, really, as it is quite a big code and I use several loops to get to it. The last part of generating the Gxx's is:_______________eval([Gxx ' = conj(' spinn ').*' spinn ';'])

Comment: Is it possible that you could put them all into a single matrix by appending new ones as columns in an existing matrix, rather than creating an entirely new vector?